# cv2 python is not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Why is `import cv2` not working in python3  after installing opencv?
i have tried this, but error is shown

```
import numpy
import cv2
img=cv2.imread('a.png',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
```

Comment: I've improved the code-formatting. For getting more help you should post the actual error message within your question.

Comment: Also, instead of `0`, use `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`. It makes it easier for readers to sort out what you're trying to do.